# Network connection timeouts when using Spotify linux client

Tags: linux, networking, kde, kubuntu, spotify

since I've installed the Spotify client on my linux machine, I always get network timeouts when using it. I have tried several versions of the client but it doesn't seem to help.

What I'm currently using:

- OS: Kubuntu 21.04
- Spotify version: 1:1.1.55.498.gf9a83c60

Here is a ping output:

```
$ ping 10.0.0.200 -O
PING 10.0.0.200 (10.0.0.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.05 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.75 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.28 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=3.26 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=4.42 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=2.49 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=4.94 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=3.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=3.93 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=4.74 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=3.67 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=4.61 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=3.11 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=4.01 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=3.15 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=3.43 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=3.79 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=3.89 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=3.43 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=3.76 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=3.52 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=4.10 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=5.15 ms
no answer yet for icmp_seq=24
no answer yet for icmp_seq=25
no answer yet for icmp_seq=26
no answer yet for icmp_seq=27
no answer yet for icmp_seq=28
no answer yet for icmp_seq=29
no answer yet for icmp_seq=30
no answer yet for icmp_seq=31
no answer yet for icmp_seq=32
no answer yet for icmp_seq=33
no answer yet for icmp_seq=34
no answer yet for icmp_seq=35
no answer yet for icmp_seq=36
no answer yet for icmp_seq=37
no answer yet for icmp_seq=38
no answer yet for icmp_seq=39
no answer yet for icmp_seq=40
no answer yet for icmp_seq=41
no answer yet for icmp_seq=42
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=2.82 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.200: icmp_seq=44 ttl=64 time=2.54 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.200 ping statistics ---
44 packets transmitted, 25 received, 43.1818% packet loss, time 43495ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.489/3.763/5.154/0.681 ms
```

It's always just short timeouts, but at random times. I cannot ping anything except localhost and also cannot get pinged from other devices. I have also tried installing the client in a vm with the same OS I have installed and there I don't have any issues.

So is there a way I can debug what exactly the issue is or do I have to completely reinstall my OS?

Edit:
I switched to using 2.4 GHz instead of 5 GHz and now it seems to work without timeouts, but I will keep an eye on it.

Edit2:
I changed WiFi settings on my router, it works now without any issues.

Comment: 1. You are pinging a local host, not the spotify servers. 2. pings are unreliable and can be ignored. 3. You have not told us anything about the local network. I assume it's wireless, so I would check there first, especially whether powersave mode is on.

Comment: @Bib Yes, it is a wireless network. The power management is off. I don't have the IP of spotify servers, but I can ping spotify.com, which returns the same results.

Comment: Connect via cables and retry. Check the router logs. Try another system on the wlan.

Comment: @Bib Unfortunately I have no possibility to use a cable. As I said in my post I tried it with a vm on the same physical machine and there I have no issues.